# SQL: Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, sql

**Note: I am looking for why this is happening and how to fix it, I am not looking for a workaround. This appears to be a server(SQL Server or Connection string) issue.**

I have a program that is connected to a sql 2008 database (Database A) and I have inline sql that runs that has ints and strings returned and it works fine. But I have been asked to switch to another 2008 database (Database B) and now everything is coming back as a string and I am getting a specified cast is not valid from C# where when I am connected to the sql 2008 (Database A) it does not say this. This is a inline sql statement so the sql statement is not changing and the table schema of the database is the same. Its doing this on int primary keys Anyone have any ideas?

I originally thought the was a 2000 to 2008 issue but I now have the some problem on 2008 as well. Both databases are on the same instance of sql server these are the connection strings

Connection Strings

```
  Server=Server01\instance;Database=Fraud_Micah; Trusted_Connection=yes <- Server 2008 (this one does not)
  Server=Server02\instance;Database=Fraud; Trusted_Connection=yes <- Server 2008 (this one works)
```

Both databases are at DB compatibility_level of 100

The select Statement

```
select *, delimeter, file_filetype.LocalPath, ArchiveDir, EmailList
from file_importtable 
join file_filetype on file_importtable.FileTypeID = file_filetype.ID
where importsuccessdate is null and transferdate is not null
and remotediscoverdate is not null 
and OriginalFileName in ('Test987.xml.pgp')
```

`fileTypeID` is where its breaking -> `InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.`

C# Code (Note reader is type SQLDataReader)

```
if (!(reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("FileTypeID"))))
{
    file.FileTypeID = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("FileTypeID"));
}
```

Here is the column definition: `[FileTypeID] [int] NULL`, there is no null values in the table.

I don't think the C# code comes from this, its a int? `public int? FileTypeID { get; set; }`

In debug mode: `reader["FileTypeID"]` -> "1" it is in fact a string but why when I connect to a 2008 database would it return a 1 instaed of a "1"

2008 Table A Def

```
[ProcessSuccessDate] [datetime] NULL,
[ProcessSuccessUser] [datetime] NULL,
[FileTypeID] [int] NULL,
[HoldDate] [datetime] NULL,
```

2008 Table B Def

```
ProcessSuccessDate] [datetime] NULL,
[ProcessSuccessUser] [datetime] NULL,
[FileTypeID] [int] NULL,
[HoldDate] [datetime] NULL,
```

`file.FileTypeID = (int)reader["FileTypeID"];` yields the same result.

Doing a

```
     file.FileTypeID (int)reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("FileTypeID"));
```

does work but I don't want to do that for every column that already should be coming back as a int also writing sql like this

```
     select Convert(int, FileTypeID) as FileTypeId, delimeter, file_filetype.LocalPath, ArchiveDir, EmailList
```

can get around the issue as well, however I want to know why I have to do this if I already set the type as a int in the table. I might as well put all the types as strings in the table. At this point I am not looking for a workaround I want to understand why its not working like it should be.

Comment: Does the error message tell you what types were involved? Can you post the full error message?

Comment: I have updated the question with the answers

Comment: When you run the SQL on the server, I'd assume you receive a valid set of data, correct? Or does it give you the error when it is run on the server?

Comment: what happens when you the query manually with management studio?

Comment: in management studio it runs just fine

Comment: You are certain `FileTypeID` is in fact an `int` (and not a `long`, etc.)?

Comment: Then the error most likely comes from the C# code. What type is file.FileTypeID defined as?

Comment: @KreepN updated answer I don't think its C# but maybe you have an sugguestion

Comment: Can you not debug this visual studio can see what value is coming back eg in the Quick Watch window put: reader["FileTypeID"]

Comment: @mouters "1" is what it returns

Comment: Really, `"1"` and not `1`?  (that's a string!)

Comment: thats what I have been saying! why is it returning a string it doesn't on 2008 but it does on 2000

Comment: Can you re-verify the schema is the same in your 2000 and 2008 databases? The only thing that makes sense to me right now is that column changing to a `varchar`.

Comment: @AdamV Just did a diff on the tables datatypes are the same for 2008 and 2000

Comment: Is the behavior any different if you specify the column names in your query instead of using *? Also, what does reader.GetDataTypeName(reader.GetOrdinal("FileTypeID")) return?

Comment: file.FileTypeID = (int)reader["FileTypeID"]; this yields the same result

Comment: Do you try casting to Int32? (Nullable<Int32>) instead - then preforming var intResult = (nullIntResult ?? (int?)0).Value;

Comment: For debugging purposes, output `reader["FileTypeID"].GetType().ToString()` and see what it gives you.

Comment: @DannyVarod Change the type to just a int 

 file.FileTypeID = (int)reader["FileTypeID"]; fails the same way

Comment: I had similar problem. When I developed my ASP.NET application on Windows 7 I used Convert.ToDecimal(...) and everything worked fine. But when I deployed it to Windows Server 2008 it provided invalid cast exception. But when I changed it to Convert.ToInt16(...) it worked fine on Server 2008 but not on Windows 7. Try casting to Int64 or something else and use Convert.To..... May be it can help

Comment: what happens if you put an explicit cast in the sql? convert(int, FileTypeId)

Comment: @mfussenegger This seems to work but I don't want to convert every column that is already supposed to be a int to a int in sql.

Comment: @MicahArmantrout but it shows that there is something wrong server side. I am not really familiar with sql server 2000. Maybe there are some kind of options to control that behavior?

Comment: @mfussenegger Yes it does show  that there is something wrong server side and I appreciate that!

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you using a `SqlDataReader` or maybe something else like an `OleDbDataReader`?

Comment: Excellent Question it is a SqlDataReader

Comment: What does `reader["FileTypeID"].GetType()` return in each case?

Comment: System.String() there is a single record coming back

Comment: Initially you said you had 2x2008 sql servers: One works one doesn't. Then in the comments you say it works on 2008 but not 2000. Please clarify that point completly and also post all your connection strings.. maybe even the block of code where you execute the sql..

Comment: Yes you are right originally I orignally thought it was cause one was on SQL 2000 and one was on sql 2008 but I moved the database back up to 2008 and it did the same thing

Comment: Tried to compare the database options? Using sys.databases

Comment: How would I go about doing that ?

Comment: Are both databases on the same compatability level? Can you restore the database that "works" to the server that doesn't work?! This way you'll know if it's the database's fault or the server's fault!

Comment: They are now on the same server. Where can I check the compatability level and does that apply to inline sql  ?

Comment: select compatibility_level from sys.databases where name = 'Fraud'.

Comment: Database A = 100 Database b = 80 B is the one not working How can I get them to be equal ?

Comment: From Management Studio -> RMC Database -> Properties -> Options -> select the correct compatibility level

Comment: I moved it to 100 and did not fix the issue

Comment: So now they are both on the same server.. one is working and one is not? EASY. delete the one that's not working and forget it ever existed. Make as many copies as you want from the one that works :D

Comment: yes if it were that simple I would

Comment: Have you tried Redgate Sql Compare (suggested below)?  It'll show you any differences between your two DBs.  It would have shown if you the compatability mode difference.  Generate a script to apply the schema changes, anything it wants to do is a difference.  See if there are any other differences.

Comment: Silly question... you're running the same program from the same machine and connecting to two DBs, one works and one doesn't. Correct?

Comment: Where did that comment go about what was actually changed? That could be useful to someone out there, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the scheme of things I desided to delete the table and recreate it using

[script table as] ->  [create]

from the same table that was giving me issues, then a reinserted all the same data. This resolved the issue. So I don't believe the DML of the Table changed and the data did not change either but this is what resolved my issue.

Answer (score 10):

Both tables you list show `int` as the data type, but it sounds like those are two versions of the same table in two different databases.

I believe the OTHER table, the one that you `JOIN` to, has a different data type in one database.

**What is the datatype of `File_fileType.Id` in both DBs?**

Your `JOIN`:

`join file_filetype on file_importtable.FileTypeID = file_filetype.ID`

Is causing an implicit conversion.

[image]

The chart above shows how SQL Server allows or executes data type conversions.

Can you show the DDL for both versions of both tables in the above `JOIN`?

Answer (score 7):

To me it sounds like there is some wacky configuration setting that is going to be hard to find.  There is a tool out there called [Redgate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) that does an **amazing** job at detecting differences between database schemas.

They have a 14-day trial.  I would try downloading it and running a comparison between your databases.

Answer (score 3):

do the SQL collation's match? If your experiencing different behaviour between databases this could be your issue. Right click on each database and select properties, the collation should be specified as something like *Latin1_General_CI_AS* If they're different it's definitely something to rule out.

Comment: I would not have know that but yes, unfortunately both Collations do match and they are SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: OK, just to check, the datatype in the db's match?

Comment: Have you tried attaching a SQL server profiller to your Db's, see if there is any difference in how the SQL is run? Is one using EXEC where as the other is processing the SQL directly?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to cast from string.

```
file.FileTypeID = int.Parse((string)reader["FileTypeID"]);
```

EDIT: if you want a workaround that should work for BOTH sql server 2008 and 2000

```
file.FileTypeID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["FileTypeID"]);
```

Comment: if it doesn't answer the question

Comment: If you don't want to cast then I suspect you will have to change something in your provider, are you using JET or the standard ADO.net provider?

Comment: I am using System.Data.SqlClient I would think that would be fine

Comment: Not sure what that is, are you using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx (`SqlConnection`) and passing a connection string?  EDIT: okay I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing it, but I posted a workaround that will work for both 2008 and 2000 simutaniously.

Comment: I don't think he wants a workaround so much as he'd like to know what is the cause. He can't case every column for this oddity in the future.

Comment: @KreepN I agree, but sometimes you also just need it to work asap.

Comment: I hear ya! :). I'll admit I'm rather baffled myself as to why it does this.

Answer (score 1):

Visual studio (edition Premium and Ultimate according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833435.aspx)) comes with a database compare tool - you select two databases, it shows you the diff and gives you a set of scripts that move one to the state of other. Start there and try and sniff out the configuration that differs (as I would expect this to a be a configuration issue). Check out Data\Schema Compare and Data\Data Compare in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

The existence of at least one bug is already acknowledged. Since I don't have the whole image it's difficult to be precise. Therefore I suggest two checks.

The first check should be on both databases using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS (it's more than enough for the required level) to verify that schemas are identical. You may read more about INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933218(v=sql.80).aspx (SQL 2000) or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348 (SQL 2008). The same information from different sources.

Sample:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;
```

If schemas are identical then there may be a bug in the code that is not visible in the parts you have presented. To vefity that everything is correct with you full code make a simple check by changing your select statement as follows:

```
select CAST(fileTypeID as int), ..., file_filetype.LocalPath, ArchiveDir, EmailList
from file_importtable 
join file_filetype on file_importtable.FileTypeID = file_filetype.ID
where importsuccessdate is null and transferdate is not null
and remotediscoverdate is not null 
and OriginalFileName in ('Test987.xml.pgp')
```

If it fails, then run in debug mode a step by step test using a breakpoint and F11. (Sometimes going back to the roots may help us to see what is invisible infront of our eyes - more unlikely in this case).

By following the above you will find the cause (hopefully).

One last tip (which may be your first step before doing anything else): be sure that your sql servers are patched with the latest service packs.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you haven't resolved this perhaps try the `GetSqlInt32` method instead.

```
file.FileTypeID = reader.GetSqlInt32((fieldTypeIDOrdinal).ToNullableInt32();
```

**Note** I've not included the `IsDBNull` check since, combining `SqlInt32` with `ToNullableInt32` copes with this.

Where `ToNullableInt32` is an extension method.

```
public static int? ToNullableInt32(this SqlInt32 value)
{
    return value.IsNull ? (int?) null : value.Value;
}
```

As a side note you mentioned this is a performance priority app, in which case you might want to precompute your ordinal values rather than having this `reader.GetOrdinal("FileTypeID")` every loop of your `reader.Read()`

Comment: I am almost positive there is something wrong with the database or connection string but I am not sure what

Comment: Yes I think its also something to do with the database setup or the connection string/data provider.

Comment: Out of interest have you tried creating a simple sample project (basic console app for example) connecting to a simple database, one table, one column setup where the column is of type `int`? Could probably knock something like that up in 5 mins and may help to isolate that's its either your code or the database...

Comment: Did this and still got the same issue

Answer (score 0):

`file.FileTypeID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["FileTypeID"]);`
  **instead of** 
`file.FileTypeID = (int)reader["FileTypeID"];`

Comment: This is the same concept, a workaround, I am looking for a reason why things are working this way not to sweep it under the rug. Thanks!